# Formatting the results of a query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have the following table:

```
first  second
A      1
A      1
A      2
B      1
B      2
C      1
C      1
```

If I run the following query:

```
select first, second, count(second) from tbl group by first, second
```

It will produce a table with the following information:

```
first  second  count(second)
A      1       2
A      2       1
B      1       1
B      2       1
C      1       2
```

How can I write the query so that I am given the information with the options from the second column as columns and the values for those columns being the count like this:

```
first  1  2
A      2  1
B      1  1
C      2  0
```

Comment: Does SQLite have a pivot function? I know that it didn't last I checked, but that was QUITE a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT  "first",
        SUM(CASE WHEN "second" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "1",
        SUM(CASE WHEN "second" = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "2"
FROM tbl
GROUP BY "first"
```

Comment: CASE was the solution. Thanks!